# Concurrent select queries split by row ids Vs one query

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

When `SELECT` querying one table `l`, no joins, with billions of rows, is it a good idea to run concurrent queries by splitting the query into multiple queries, split into distinct subsets/ranges by the indexes column, say integer primary key `id`?
Or does Postgres internally do this already, leading to no significant gain in speed for the end user?

I have two use cases:

1. getting the total count of rows
2. getting the list of `id`s

**Edit-1:** The query has conditional clause on columns where one of the columns is not indexed, and the other columns are indexed

```
SELECT id 
FROM l 
WHERE indexed_column-1='A' 
  AND indexed_column-2='B' 
  AND not_indexed_column-1='C'
```

Comment: @laurenz Thanks for making the question more readable, useful!

Comment: Your edit is a game-changer. Now it's more about the best indexing strategy. I suggest to start a new question instead - with all relevant details. Consider instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I see. Thanks for the pointer to instructions page, will keep in mind the next time. Changing indexing strategy, at least for now, is not an option I have.

Answer (score 3):

Postgres has parallelization built in since version 9.6. (Improved in current versions.) It will be much more efficient than manually splitting a `SELECT` on a big table.

You can set the number of [`max_parallel_workers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PARALLEL-WORKERS) to your needs to optimize.

While you are only interested in the `id` column, it may help to have an index on `(id)` (given if it's the PK) and fulfill prerequisites for an [index-only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, we are using older version of Postgres, as of now.

Comment: @DevH: what **is** your Postgres version?

Comment: We are still at 9.4.

Answer (score 3):

In the case where you want to count the number of rows, you can just let PostgreSQL's internal query parallelization do the work. It will be faster, and the result will be consistent.

In the case where you want to get the list of primary keys, it depends on the `WHERE` conditions of the query. If you are selecting only a few rows, parallel query will do nicely.

If you want *all* `id`s of the table, PostgreSQL will probably *not* choose a parallel plan, because the cost of exchanging so many values between the worker processes will outweigh the advantages of parallelization. In that case, you may be faster with parallel sessions as you envision.

Comment: By Postgresql internal parallelization, are you referring to Parallel Query, added in 9.6? We are still at 9.4.

Answer (score 0):

This 4-column composite index would probably be faster than using parallelism:

```
INDEX(indexed_column-1, indexed_column-2,  -- first, in either order
      not_indexed_column-1, id)
```